# How can I change color of points in a PCD?

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

Is there a way to change the color of points in a pcd? I am trying to extract objects from pcd but I am not sure if that is the correct object that I am extracting so I want to verify if those are the correct points that I am extracting.

Edit: I am looking for something like this:
[Change color of points in point cloud].[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnW2P.png)

P.S I have used image editor for this image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain what you have tried?  If you are unsure, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple pointclouds and need to visualize in a PCL viewer, each in a different color, the following would do

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud; // your pointcloud
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer; // your PCL viewer
float r, g, b; // specify color values you need

pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> color(cloud, r, g, b);
viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud, color, "a_name_for_the_cloud");
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I am extracting objects from JSON and hence i need to verify if the points that I am extracting are the same as the once I want to extract and hence I need the change of color so that I can visually verify.

Comment: Your question is not clear. So you don't have two pointclouds? Please update the question with a sample code showing the way you expect it to behave

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to change color of points using open3d library.

```html
from open3d import *
import numpy as np
pcd = io.read_point_cloud("frag_116.ply")
visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
np_colors = np.array(pcd.colors)
np_colors[3000:45000,2] = 0.24
pcd.colors = Vector3dVector(np_colors)
visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

`